# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in express with firebase auth

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, express

I made an authentification system in express using firebase auth. 
I created an endpoint in express like this :

```
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('logare...');
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.parola)
        .then(user => {
            res.json({ succes: true, msg: "te-ai autentificat cu succes" });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('date invalide');
            res.json({ succes: false, msg: 'date invalide', errCode: err.code });
        })
})
```

then I created a function in my font-end js file for send request to server :

```
const autentificare = async (email, parola) => {
    return await fetch('https://cm-api-1.herokuapp.com/users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            pasword: parola
        })
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.status)
            return res.json();
        });
};
```

In my app.js file I created submit event for verfy email and pasword:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = emailDom.value;
    const parola = parolaDom.value;
    await autentificare(email, parola)
        .then(data => {
            if (data.succes) {
                console.log('ok datele sunt valide')
            } else {
                console.log('date invalide')
            }
        })
});
```

When I submited the form in console it shows me this errors: `POST https://cm-api-1.herokuapp.com/users/login 500 (Internal Server Error)`and `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` My api it's deployed on heroku.
I don't know what I missed

Comment: You are sending an object that has `email` and `password` as properties and you're accessing `req.body.email` and `req.body.parola` on the server. Tine-o pe engleza.

Comment: ok asa am sa fac:))

Answer (score 0):

From my experience writing REST APIs, this error usually occur when there's some syntax error or an exception being caught in the API itself. The code looks fine but the HTML error 500 indicates it's not on the client end of things.

I have no experience with firebase and express, i've mostly written REST APIs with Swagger and php.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to some issue with the JSON body content. Something like unescaped double quotes. Inspect what is being sent and received.

Read more about it here - https://www.kevinleary.net/syntax-error-unexpected-token-json-position-0/